# How to make ASP.NET Core MVC routes generation relative?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, home-assistant

## Context - the application

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application using `netcoreapp2.2` (dotnet core 2.2). This application is distributed as a Docker image and it's working well. It's an *Add-On* for *HASS.IO*, an automated environment for *Home Assistant* based on docker. Everything works well.

## The missing feature in my app: HASS.IO's ingress

But... I want to make use of a *HASS.IO* feature called *Ingress*: https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/en/next/hassio_addon_presentation.html#ingress

The goal of this feature is to allow *Home Assistant* to route the http traffic to the add-on without having to manage the authentication part and without requiring the system owner to setup a port mapping on its firewall for the communication.  So it's a very nice feature.

## MVC routing paths are absolute

To use HASS.IO ingress, the application needs to provide relative paths for navigation. By example, when the user is loading the url `https://my.hass.io/a0a0a0a0_myaddon/`, the *add-on* container will receive a `/` http request. It means all navigation in the app must be relative.

By example, while on the root page (`https://my.hass.io/a0a0a0a0_myaddon/` translated to a `HTTP GET /` for the container), we add the following razor code:

```html
<a asp-action="myAction" asp-route-id="123">this is a link</a>
```

We'll get a resulting html like this, which is wrong in this case:

```html
<a href="/Home/myAction/123">this is a link</a> <!-- THIS IS A WRONG LINK! -->
```

It's wrong because it's getting translated to `https://my.hass.io/Home/myAction/123` by the browser while the correct address would be `https://my.hass.io/a0a0a0a0_myaddon/Home/myAction/123`.

To fix this, I need the resulting html to be like that:

```html
<!-- THIS WOULD BE THE RIGHT LINK [option A] -->
<a href="Home/myAction/123">this is a link</a>

<!-- THIS WOULD BE GOOD TOO [option B] -->
<a href="/a0a0a0a0_myaddon/Home/myAction/123">this is a link</a>
```

## The problem to solve

[option A]

Is there a way to setup the MVC's routing engine to output relative paths instead of absolute ones? That would solve my problem.

It also means when you're on `https://my.hass.io/a0a0a0a0_myaddon/Home/myAction/123` and you want to go *home*, the result should be

```html
<a href="../..">Return home</a>
```

**---OR---**

[option B]

Another approach would be to find a way to discover the actual absolute path and find a way to prepend it in the MVC's routing mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question.  I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it worked!

## 1. Create a wrapper for the existing `IUrlHelper`

This one converts absolute paths to relative ones...

```cs
private class RelativeUrlHelper : IUrlHelper
{
    private readonly IUrlHelper _inner;
    private readonly HttpContext _contextHttpContext;

    public RelativeUrlHelper(IUrlHelper inner, HttpContext contextHttpContext)
    {
        _inner = inner;
        _contextHttpContext = contextHttpContext;
    }

    private string MakeUrlRelative(string url)
    {
        if (url.Length == 0 || url[0] != '/')
        {
            return url; // that's an url going elsewhere: no need to be relative
        }

        if (url.Length > 2 && url[1] == '/')
        {
            return url; // That's a "//" url, means it's like an absolute one using the same scheme
        }

        // This is not a well-optimized algorithm, but it works!
        // You're welcome to improve it.
        var deepness = _contextHttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/').Length - 2;
        if (deepness == 0)
        {
            return url.Substring(1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < deepness; i++)
            {
                url = i == 0 ? ".." + url : "../" + url;
            }
        }

        return url;
    }

    public string Action(UrlActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return MakeUrlRelative(_inner.Action(actionContext));
    }

    public string Content(string contentPath)
    {
        return MakeUrlRelative(_inner.Content(contentPath));
    }

    public bool IsLocalUrl(string url)
    {
        if (url?.StartsWith("../") ?? false)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _inner.IsLocalUrl(url);
    }

    public string RouteUrl(UrlRouteContext routeContext) => _inner.RouteUrl(routeContext);

    public string Link(string routeName, object values) => _inner.Link(routeName, values);

    public ActionContext ActionContext => _inner.ActionContext;
}
```

## 2. Create a wrapper for `IUrlHelperFactory`

```cs
public class RelativeUrlHelperFactory : IUrlHelperFactory
{
    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory _previous;

    public RelativeUrlHelperFactory(IUrlHelperFactory previous)
    {
        _previous = previous;
    }

    public IUrlHelper GetUrlHelper(ActionContext context)
    {
        var inner = _previous.GetUrlHelper(context);

        return new RelativeUrlHelper(inner, context.HttpContext);
    }
}
```

## 3. Wrap the `IUrlHelper` in DI/IoC

Put this in the `ConfigureServices()` of the `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
services.Decorate<IUrlHelperFactory>((previous, _) => new RelativeUrlHelperFactory(previous));
```

- **IMPORTANT**: You need to install the nuget package `Scrutor` for that https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scrutor/.

## Finally...

I posted my solution as a PR there: https://github.com/yllibed/Zigbee2MqttAssistant/pull/2